# multiple establishing connectoins to capistrano servers get stuck. (Just on my computer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Deployment on other computers works fine. Deploying on a single webserver works fine but just on multiple servers gets stuck. If i shell/deploy same thing.

```
    cap prd_es shell
    ~/code/------_git[master]% cap prd_es shell
      * executing `prd_es'
        triggering start callbacks for `shell'
      * executing `multistage:ensure'
      * executing `shell'
    ====================================================================
    Welcome to the interactive Capistrano shell! This is an experimental
    feature, and is liable to change in future releases. Type 'help' for
    a summary of how to use the shell.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    cap> echo
    [establishing connection(s) to web1.------.com, web2.------.com, web3.------.com, web4.------.com, web5.------.com, web6.------.com, web7.------.com, admin.------.com]
```

I am using

```
capistrano (2.5.2)
rails (2.1.2)
ruby (1.8.7)
```

I am on osx 10.6

/etc/hosts

```
    ***.***.***.*** admin
    ***.***.***.*** web1
    ***.***.***.*** web2
    ***.***.***.*** web3
    ***.***.***.*** web4
    ***.***.***.*** web5
    ***.***.***.*** web6
    ***.***.***.*** web7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another version of capistrano worked out well